# Enable / Disable SSL on ASP.NET Core projects in Development

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core project, I am using SSL in Production so I have in Startup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc(x => {
    x.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
  });  
  // Remaining code ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder, IHostingEnvironment environment, ILoggerFactory logger, IApplicationLifetime lifetime) {
  RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
  rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToHttps();
  builder.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
  // Remaining code ...
}
```

It works fine in Production but not in Development. I would like to either:

1. Disable SSL in Development;
2. Make SSL work in Development because with current configuration it is not.
   Do I need to set any PFX files on my local machine?
   I am working on multiple projects so that might create problems?

Answer (score 17):

You can configure a service using the `IConfigureOptions<T>` interface.

```cs
internal class ConfigureMvcOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public ConfigureMvcOptions(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            options.SslPort = 44523;
        }
        else
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add this class as a singleton:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    var builder = services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ConfigureMvcOptions>();
}
```

Concerning the SSL point, you can easily use SSL using IIS Express ([source](https://www.meziantou.net/2016/10/09/iis-express-ssl))

[image: Configure SSL in SSL]

Comment: This is the right answer. IIS Express makes it easy to use a self-signed cert to test locally. You may have to set the `SslPort` property on `MvcOptions` in order to make the redirect work properly in dev, FYI.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use IIS Express then delete the https-address in Project Properties -> Debug section -> Under "Web Server Settings" -> Uncheck "Enable SSL".

[image: ProjectProperties]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please ensure you answer the question and that you fully explain your answer.

Comment: Dear mr @Simon.S.A., this is how you can disable ssl if you want to debug without using iis.

Answer (score 5):

just comment this line:

rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToHttps();

or in new versions of .Net core on Startup.cs comment:

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Answer (score -3):

Using `#if !DEBUG`, like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc(x => {
    #if !DEBUG
    x.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    #endif
  });  
  // Remaining code ...
}
```